# Error 1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax" Python Django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, mysql-connector-python

I am receiving multiple SQL errors in my Django website post setup. I believe it's a version issue but can't point it out.
The site was created with mysqlclient, but I have moved it to mysqlconnector.

Full example error messages are:
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION max_matches = 1000' at line 1")

(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group, denomination, location, affiliation, released_by, affiliations, filetypes' at line 1")

MySQL Version: 8.0 (used just for sphinx)
Database using Postgres
Using mysqlconnector
**init**.py (main for site) imports pymysql, using install_as_MySQLdb()

I auto-created models.py using python manage.py inspectdb>models.py, but am not sure if that even helped anything (the site was given with model files only controlled by app).

Django is 2.0.13, python is 3.9 running with Six

Comment: "Database using Postgres Using mysqlconnector" -> Postgresql and MySQL are different database implementations.  Why are these error messages suggesting that you are trying to use MySQL connectors to connect to a Postgresql database server?

Comment: @snakecharmerb To be honest I have no idea where the issue is, I just know that the exception happen at lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/err.py in raise_mysql_exception, line 143. But since its an SQL syntax thing, it has to do something with one of the interpreters right?

Answer (score 0):

The `OPTION max_matches = 1000` is as far as I know Sphinx Search syntax, not supported by MySQL or PostgreSQL. Sphinx Search supports the MySQL protocol, so you can connect to it with a MySQL client. But Sphinx Search supports some query syntax that MySQL does not. If you try to run a Sphinx Search query against an actual MySQL instance, MySQL won't recognize it. I think that's what is happening in your first error.

The second error is simply that you're using a reserved keyword `group` as a column name in an SQL query. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Comment: Thanks Bill that's really useful! I do have some questions though.... with sphinx an sql connection does need to take place or else you get a "connection refused" error, right? So how would you run sphinx without it.  I've looked into the second and its definitely multiple syntax issues with it running lines through postgres that are not postgres format, as well as other things... I will keep looking into it to see where exactly the formatting is coming from since I am running psycopg2 as well

Comment: You can run Sphinx Search as a standalone daemon. I'm not going to attempt to recreate the [documentation](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/installing-debian.html) here. FWIW, I mostly see people have switched to ElasticSearch these days.